# One TableViewController with 2 sections linking to 1 DetailView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

So In my project I have one HistoryTableViewController which contains 2 sections. One section is the PeopleYouOwe and the other section is a group of PeopleWhoOweYou. How would I be able to hook up this one tableviewcontroller and link it to a detail view that will display different data according to my sections?

Answer (score 2):

**Try below approach using prepareForSegue -** 

creat tableView outlet named **myTableView**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

 NSIndexPath *path = [self.myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

 if (path.section == 0)
 {
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PeopleYouOwe"])
     {
         PeopleYouOwe *peopleYouOweVC = segue.destinationViewController;
         // you can get data of cell as array[path.row]
     }
 }
 else if (path.section == 1)
 {
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PeopleWhoOweYou"])
     {
         PeopleWhoOweYou *peopleWhoOweYou = segue.destinationViewController;
          // you can get data of cell as array[path.row]
     }

 }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the delegate methods provided with UITableViews like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
    NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
    if(section == 0) // example
    {
        // do whatever
    }
    else if (section == 1)
    {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

If this is not what you're looking for you will need to provide more details and ideally some code to show what you already have. Your question is vague.

Comment: my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is screwed up, so I think I'll use the -(void)prepareForSegue. Can your code still apply in that method?

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer prepareForSegue, you can use something like:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

then take action based on section and row.